# How to print a Groovy variable in Jenkins?

Tags: variables, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following code within a Jenkins pipeline:

```
stage ('Question') {
    try {
        timeout(time: 1, unit: 'MINUTES') {
            userInput = input message: 'Choose server to publish to:', ok: '', parameters: [
                [$class: 'hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: 'pc-ensureint\nother-server', description: 'Choose server to publish to:', name: 'server']
        ] 
      }
    } catch (err) {
        userInput = [server: 'pc-ensureint'] // if an error is caught set this value
    }
}

node () {
    println ${server}
}
```

I'm trying to troubleshoot a problem with the `server` variable which is set in the `ChoiceParameterDefinition`.

When I run the build, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps [AddInteractivePromotion, ArtifactoryGradleBuild, ArtifactoryMavenBuild, ConanAddRemote, ConanAddUser, InitConanClient, MavenDescriptorStep, RunConanCommand, ansiblePlaybook, archive, artifactoryDownload, artifactoryPromoteBuild, artifactoryUpload, bat, build, catchError, checkout, collectEnv, deleteDir, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, dockerPullStep, dockerPushStep, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, getArtifactoryServer, getContext, getDatabaseConnection, git, input, isUnix, library, libraryResource, load, mail, milestone, newArtifactoryServer, newBuildInfo, newGradleBuild, newMavenBuild, node, parallel, properties, publishBuildInfo, pwd, readFile, readTrusted, resolveScm, retry, script, sh, sleep, sql, stage, stash, step, svn, timeout, timestamps, tool, unarchive, unstash, validateDeclarativePipeline, waitForQualityGate, waitUntil, withContext, withCredentials, withDockerContainer, withDockerRegistry, withDockerServer, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, ws, xrayScanBuild] or symbols [all, allOf, always, ant, antFromApache, antOutcome, antTarget, any, anyOf, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, batchFile, booleanParam, branch, buildButton, buildDiscarder, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, choice, choiceParam, cleanWs, clock, cloud, command, configFile, configFileProvider, cron, crumb, defaultView, demand, disableConcurrentBuilds, docker, dockerfile, downloadSettings, downstream, dumb, envVars, environment, expression, file, fileParam, filePath, fingerprint, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, git, github, githubPush, gradle, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, installSource, jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jgitapache, jnlp, jobName, junit, label, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, legacy, legacySCM, list, local, location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, modernSCM, msbuild, msbuildError, msbuildWarning, myView, node, nodeProperties, nonStoredPasswordParam, none, not, overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus, parameters, password, pattern, pipeline-model, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plugin, pollSCM, projectNamingStrategy, proxy, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, remotingCLI, run, runParam, schedule, scmRetryCount, search, security, shell, skipDefaultCheckout, skipStagesAfterUnstable, slave, stackTrace, standard, status, string, stringParam, swapSpace, text, textParam, tmpSpace, toolLocation, unsecured, upstream, usernameColonPassword, usernamePassword, viewsTabBar, weather, withSonarQubeEnv, zfs, zip] or globals [Artifactory, currentBuild, docker, env, params, pipeline, scm]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:149)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:151)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:149)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:146)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:123)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:123)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:16)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:16)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor637.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:165)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:242)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:230)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

As far as I know, `server` is a groovy variable and thus I'm supposed to be able to access it using `${` `}`.

So I've tried:

```
echo ${server}
print ${server}
println ${server}
println "${server}"
```

But no matter what I try I keep getting this error.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It should just work with `println "${server}"` or just `println server`

Comment: But it doesn't... Otherwise I wouldn't ask this question...

Comment: Read up on [Groovy string interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation)

Comment: well @EdRandall, you're probably right, but in the question the 'server' parameter is a choice parameter and not a boolean one

Comment: Also it doesn't work with single quotes like `println('Server: ${server}')`, only with double quotes: `println("Server: ${server}")`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The following code worked for me:

```
echo userInput
```

Comment: Also works with generic webhook  trigger plugin and pipeline job

Comment: Note that `echo` does not work in Groovy itself - only in Jenkins. `println` works in both.

Comment: @CoredusK is probably right, but the question were about choice parameter and not a boolean one

Comment: sendEmail("describe-ec2 pipeline has completed Successfully", "Sending Body ${body}", 'ashish.karpe@abcd.com', ' ') ........... I am getting error groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: body for class: WorkflowScript

Answer (score 48):

You shouldn't use `${varName}` when you're outside of strings, you should just use `varName`. Inside strings you use it like this; `echo "this is a string ${someVariable}";`. Infact you can place an general java expression inside of `${...}`; `echo "this is a string ${func(arg1, arg2)}`.